# print variables created with for loop

Tags: php

i want to do this with php without use array or something like that.

I want to print

10

20

but I get this or errors but not as I want

$m1

$m2

```
<?php

$m1=10; 
$m2=20;

for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
 echo  "$"."m$i"; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Do it like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
    echo ${"m$i"}; 
}
```

This will create a variable name of `m1` and `m2` and then evaluate them.

Example: http://3v4l.org/qstg7

Comment: But don't. The variable namespace isn't a toy to play with, this is a lousy idea, and if you want arrays you know where to find them.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't want to use an array it still looks like the best approach based on the little information we have:

```
<?php

$m[1]=10; 
$m[2]=20;

foreach($m as $v){
 echo  $v. "\n"; //or perhaps you want html <br> 
}

?>
```